# Creating smooth curve from sampled poitns

Tags: ios, graphics, opengl-es

I am creating sort of a 'paint' application in which use can draw free curves. If i draw the sampled points as is, the curve does not look smooth.

I tried the algorithm in the following tutorial: http://www.merowing.info/2012/04/drawing-smooth-lines-with-cocos2d-ios-inspired-by-paper/#.U2e1EK2Sy-Q
This tutorial create smooth curves using quad bezier curves.

The result is OK, but still not as good as i would like and i can still see the curve 'breaks'. How can i improve the curves and make them smoother, similar to 'paper' application?

Comment: This question is asked a lot. If your problem is what I think it is, you have too many sampled points. If, for instance, you sample a stylus anytime it moves a lot of the points are going to be linear and you cannot smooth lines (*in the proper geometric sense of the word*). You might pre-process the data to throw out or reduce the number of co-linear input points or simply reduce the sample rate. Can you add a screenshot of your problem to the question?

Comment: How should i reduce number of inputs?

Comment: Off the top of my head, something like [this](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2013/10/24/get-simpler-polygons-by-removing-collinear-points/). There are also image/signal processing techniques that could be applied, but that is getting to the point of overkill. You do not necessarily want to remove ***all*** redundant collinear points, but you do not want them spaced really closely because that will mess with any bezier smoothing you try to apply.

Comment: What if i will add a new sample only if the distance from it to the last added sample it at least X pixels (four pixels for example). Do you think it might be a good solution?